# Redux Saga Login React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm building a login feature using Redux + Redux-saga.

My problem is when I submit Form and pass it email and password. The reducer can't be received email and password that I passed.

Here is my code:

reducer.js

```
const initState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  user: {},
  error: false
}

function loginReducer(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.access_token,
        user: action.payload.user
      }
    case LOGIN_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        user: {}
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

action.js:

```
export function login(email, password) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    payload: { email, password }
  }
}

export function loginSucceeded(payload) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCEEDED,
    payload
  }
}

export function loginFailed(error) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_FAILED,
    error
  }
}
```

saga.js

```
import { callLogin } from '../../requests'

export function* login({email, password}) {
  const options = {
    email: email,
    password: password
  };

  try {
    const payload = yield call(callLogin, options);
    const { access_token } = payload;
    yield put(loginSucceeded(payload));
    localStorage.setItem('token', access_token);
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loginFailed(error));
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
}

export default function* loginPageSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(LOGIN_REQUEST, login);
}
```

LoginForm/index.js

```
  onSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const { loginAction: dispatchLogin } = this.props;
    // callLogin({email, password}); It't working
    dispatchLogin(email, password);
  }


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loginAction: (email, password) => dispatch(actionsType.login(email, password))
});
```

I tried to call immediately in `Login` form. It's work but using dispatch not working. What did I wrong here?

I check in browser XHR request. In Request Payload only have empty Object.

Comment: `dispatchLogin(email, password);` should be `loginAction(email, password);` right?

Comment: I destructuring that so `dispatchLogin ` is `loginAction`

Comment: Oh, Missed that..Whats the code of `callLogin` function?

Comment: Try passing like this `dispatchLogin({ email, password })`

Comment: Here is callLogin function 
`export const callLogin = options => request('post', LOGIN, options);`

Comment: The only diff between `callLogin({email, password});` and `dispatchLogin(email, password);` is `dispatchLogin` doesn't pass a single object like callLogin but two different values..., Try changing and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the saga is not receiving the values correctly.
Try passing email and password directly, instead of inside of a payload object:

```
export function login(email, password) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    email, 
    password
  }
}
```